# I want to make text of the anchor tag appear and disappear nice and little bit slowly

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have made the navbar with bootstrap. When I hover on one of the icon it changes to the text but it happens straight away after pointing mouse on it but I want this to be appearing little bit nice and slower like it is done on here
https://jacekjeznach.com/

my html code looks like this:

```
    <nav class='navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark'>
    <div class='container'>
        <a class='brandFont navbar-brand' href='/'>An's Resume</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
            <div>
             <a class=" about nav-item nav-link" href="#"><span class='icon'><svg class='show'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M8 8a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm2-3a2 2 0 1 1-4 0 2 2 0 0 1 4 0zm4 8c0 1-1 1-1 1H3s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4zm-1-.004c-.001-.246-.154-.986-.832-1.664C11.516 10.68 10.289 10 8 10c-2.29 0-3.516.68-4.168 1.332-.678.678-.83 1.418-.832 1.664h10z"/>
</svg></span> <span class='text'></span></a> 
                </div>


        <a class="projects nav-item nav-link" href="/projects"><span class='icon'><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-journals" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M5 0h8a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v10a2 2 0 0 1-2 2 2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2h1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h8a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H3a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H1a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h8a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v9a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2z"/>
  <path d="M1 6v-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V6h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1zm0 3v-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V9h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1zm0 2.5v.5H.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h2a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2v-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0z"/>
</svg></span><span class='text'></span></a>
                
                  <a class="contact nav-item nav-link form-inline" href="/contact"><span class='icon'><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-envelope" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M0 4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v8a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4zm2-1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v.217l7 4.2 7-4.2V4a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H2zm13 2.383l-4.758 2.855L15 11.114v-5.73zm-.034 6.878L9.271 8.82 8 9.583 6.728 8.82l-5.694 3.44A1 1 0 0 0 2 13h12a1 1 0 0 0 .966-.739zM1 11.114l4.758-2.876L1 5.383v5.73z"/>
                    
</svg></span><span class='text'></span></a>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And my CSS code like this:

```
     .about:hover .icon{
    display: none
}


.about .text::after{
    content: 'about';
    display: none;
    
}

.about:hover .text::after{
    display: block;
}
```

I have tried with transforms and transitions but I could probably do it wrong as it didn't work for me

I appreciate your help

Comment: if you are using transitions, use opacity:1, opacity:0 instead of display:none

Comment: Have you used webkit, or the transition property?

Comment: ----if I use opacity, there will be space between one icon and another but I don't want that space and that's why I used display property

Comment: ----I used transition property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make the icon & text overlapping. Apply `position:relative` to the icon wrapper (in this case, `.about`) & apply `position:absolute` to elements inside in order to adjust those elements' position.
2. Use `opacity` instead of `display` if you hope to make fade in/out transition.

Hope this help :D

```
.about {
  position: relative; 
}

.about .text {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.about .icon,
.about .text::after {
  display: block;
  transition: .2s;
}


.about:hover .icon {
  opacity: 0;
}


.about .text::after {
  content: 'about';
  opacity: 0;
}

.about:hover .text::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: HI, Thanks. It kind of works. It does the effect I wanted but I need to move that text a little, because now, when the icon disappears, the text appears on top of the icon's place rather instead of the icon's place. Not sure if you understand

Comment: I guess you can adjust the top value of the text.